# How to select all post's tags?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
// QandA
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+
| id |  title |                  content               | type | related |
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+
| 1  | title1 | content of question1                   | 0    | NULL    |
| 2  |        | content of first answer for question1  | 1    | 1       |
| 3  | title2 | content of question2                   | 0    | NULL    |
| 4  | title3 | content of question3                   | 0    | NULL    |
| 5  |        | content of second answer for question1 | 1    | 1       |
| 6  |        | content of first answer for question3  | 1    | 4       |
| 7  | title4 | content of question4                   | 0    | NULL    |
| 8  |        | content of first answer for question2  | 1    | 3       |
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------+---------+
-- type colum: it is 0 for questions and 1 for answers.
-- related column: it is NULL for questions and {the id of its own question} for answers.
```

Also I have these two other tables:

```
// interface_tags
+---------+--------+
| post_id | tag_id |
+---------+--------+
| 1       | 1      |
| 1       | 5      |
| 3       | 4      |
| 4       | 1      |
| 4       | 2      |
| 4       | 5      |
| 7       | 2      |
+---------+--------+

// tags
+----+----------+
| id | tag_name |
+----+----------+
| 1  | PHP      |
| 2  | SQL      |
| 3  | MySQL    |
| 4  | CSS      |
| 5  | Java     |
| 6  | HTML     |
| 7  | JQuery   |
+----+----------+
```

And here is my query:

```
SELECT id,
       title,
       content
FROM QandA
WHERE id = :id1 OR related = :id2

-- Note: :id1, :id2 are identical
```

---

As you see it selects both the question (`id = :id2`) and all its own answers (`related = :id3`).

**What's my question?** I need to also select all question's tags. Here is expected output:

```
-- :id = 1

// QandA
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------------+
| id |  title |                  content               |   tag      |
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------------+
| 1  | title1 | content of question1                   | PHP,JAVA   |
| 2  |        | content of first answer for question1  |            |
| 5  |        | content of second answer for question1 |            |
+----+--------+----------------------------------------+------------+
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You might want to add a SQL or MySQL tag to your question.

Comment: @j08691 I did .. thx

Comment: Just use group_concat: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat. They are a lot of samples and qüestions about it.

Comment: @danihp I can do that by a subquery: `(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i_t.tag_name) FROM tags t JOIN interface_tags i_t ON t.id = i_t.tag_id WHERE i_t.post_id = :id1) tag` ..! But it will be executed for each row *(both the question and all answers)* ..! How can I prevent a lot of useless processes?

Comment: Just do a big query with the three tables grouping by Id, title and content.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
SELECT 
   q.id,
   q.title,
   q.content,
   GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_name) AS tag
FROM QandA q
LEFT JOIN interface_tags it ON it.post_id = q.id AND q.type = 0
LEFT JOIN tags t ON t.id = it.tag_id
WHERE q.id = :id1 OR related = :id2
GROUP BY q.id
```

View schema and script execution in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/989f139/47).

Comment: If you use aliases, strive to use them throughout.

Comment: Yeah, otherwise you get ambiguous table/column errors (often). More importantly, the next guy coming along to maintain the code, even you of yours.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a LEFT join with the QandA tbale

```
     SELECT 
       a.id,
       a.title,
       a.content,
       group_concat(c.tag_name)
    FROM QandA as a
    INNER JOIN interface_tags as b  on ( a.id = b.post_id  and a.type='0')
    INNER JOIN tags as c on b.tag_id  = c.id
    LEFT  JOIN QandA as d on ( a.id = d.id and d.type ='1')
    WHERE a.id = :id1 OR a.related = :id2
    group by a.id
```

Comment: First of all please replace `?` with `)` in your query. And also those two `LEFT JOIN`s will be executed for both the question and answers. Can I use `CASE` for those `LEFT JOIN` to execute them *only* when `type=0` ?

Comment: The ? is removed .. typo .. I have one left join .. and two inner join ..the inner join for retrieve the tags should be executed only for the row of type = 0 for the rows of type 0  should be resolved the by left join.. .. for the CASE  .. remember that don't be shoudl possibile change the table name depending on type..

Comment: Unknown column 'c.tag_name' in 'field list'

Comment: `QandA` table = *1* million rows | `interface_tags` table = *800,000* rows |  `tags` table = *200* rows.